# How mount vhd on mac?

Tags: macos, mac

I have some vhd files that are fixed size.

Does anyone know how to mount a fixed-size vhd on Macos?

Comment: What is a "fixed-size vhd"?

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac, to mount a vhd , it is safer to be of fixed size, using "/usr/bin/hdiutil" according to

**`"/usr/bin/hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage  /path_to_your_vhd"`**

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename to ".img" and double click. It will mount and you can read and write to the vhd. Then "eject" after your work is done and rename the file back to ".vhd". Works like a charm!